# Как правильно использовать entity framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Как правильно использовать entity framework? Нужно создавать DbContext для каждого вызова, или создать один раз и использовать всё время жизни приложения?

**Вариант №1** (создаём REMOTE_OFFICE_3Entities для каждого вызова)

```
internal sealed class Letters : IRequestsLetters
{
    public async Task<Letter> GetLetterByIdAsync(Int32 id)
    {
        using (REMOTE_OFFICE_3Entities db = new REMOTE_OFFICE_3Entities())
        {
            return await db.Letters.FindAsync(id);
        }
    }
}
```

**Вариант №2** (единожды создаём REMOTE_OFFICE_3Entities и используем всю жизнь приложения)

```
internal sealed class Letters : IRequestsLetters
{
    private readonly REMOTE_OFFICE_3Entities db = new REMOTE_OFFICE_3Entities();

    public async Task<Letter> GetLetterByIdAsync(Int32 id)
    {
        return await this.db.Letters.FindAsync(id);
    }
}
```

Всё моё приложение и множество вызовов уже написаны по варианту №1, но сейчас когда начала появляться нагрузка, периодически я стал получать исключение такого вида:

```
Произошла ошибка базового поставщика в Open.
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: Произошла ошибка базового поставщика в Open. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Истекло время ожидания. Время ожидания истекло раньше, чем удалось получить подключение из пула. Возможно, все подключения в пуле уже используются и достигнут максимальный размер пула.
   в System.Data.Common.ADP.ExceptionWithStackTrace(Exception e)
--- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
   в System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
```

Comment: Вы там базу чем атакуете, что у вас с пулом проблемы? Ваши оба варианта к размеру пула подключений отношения не имеют

Comment: Каждое создание REMOTE_OFFICE_3Entities создаёт новое подключение, разве я не прав?

Comment: Неправ, есть пул подключений, который держит подключения к бд, когда вы отправляете запрос к базе, контекст берет подключение из пула

Comment: @tym32167, это хорошо, значит не нужно переписывать тучу кода на совместное использование DbContext. Но как мне победить ошибку при высокой нагрузке? Получается пула не хватает? Как его увеличить?

Comment: А вы  уверены, что дело именно в высокой нагрузке, а не в неоптимальных запросах? Чем вы таким базу бомбардируете?

Comment: Переписывать не надо, так как в варианте 2 вы можете удерживать соединение контекстом, т.к. Как он по умолчанию держит транзакцию (хотя я могу ошибаться). Перед увеличением пула поглядите на ваш код, может вы слишком много шлете запросов к базе? Может, количество запросов к базе можно уменьшить? Например, кешированием данных в памяти. Но таки если вы хотите пул увеличить, это делается в строке соединения https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки, код перепроверю